# Create new table with upgrade scripts in custom module

Tags: magento2, setup-upgrade

I have created a lot of tables using **InstallSchema.php** and put some data by **InstallData.php** in my custom module.

Once i want create a new table, Can i do it with upgrade scripts so i'm not create it manually in phpmyadmin? If using install schema i had to remove my module in **setup_module** table, and it makes data is reinserted while doing setup upgrade.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, we can create new table using **UpgradeSchema.php**. Inside `public function upgrade()` add below scripts:

```
$setup->startSetup();
if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '2.0.0', '<=')) {
    $installer = $setup;
    $installer->startSetup();

    $table = $installer->getConnection()
        ->newTable($installer->getTable('custom_table'))
        ->addColumn(/* put some column attribute here */);

    $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
    $installer->endSetup();
}
```