# Create new table to existing module in Magento2

Tags: magento2, installer, upgradeschema

I have created a new module and installed it, but did not include `Setup/InstallSchema.php` to create the table first time.

> Once the module is created can we create new table using `InstallSchema.php`?

I tried that, but no table is created.
After that I used `Upgradeschema.php` to try to create the table by changing the version in `etc/module.xml`.

However, I am getting `base table not found` error.

I am using below code to create table in `Setup/UpgradeSchema.php`

```
  use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
  use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
  use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
  use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;

  class UpgradeSchema implements  UpgradeSchemaInterface
 {
  public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup,  ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
   $setup->startSetup();

    if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '2.0.1', '<')) {
      $setup->getConnection()->addColumn(
        $setup->getTable("product_temp_cart"),
        'id',
        [
          "type" => Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
          "identity" => true,
          "nullable" => false,
          "primary" => true
        ]
      );
      $setup->getConnection()->addColumn(
        $setup->getTable("product_temp_cart"),
        'reference_sku',
        [
          "type" => Table::TYPE_TEXT,
          "nullable" => true
        ]
      );
      $setup->getConnection()->addColumn(
        $setup->getTable("product_temp_cart"),
        'product_sku',
        [
          "type" => Table::TYPE_TEXT,
          "nullable" => true
        ]
      );
      $setup->getConnection()->addColumn(
      $setup->getTable("product_temp_cart"),
        'customer_id',
        [
          "type" => Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
          "nullable" => false
        ]
      );
        $setup->getConnection()->addColumn(
        $setup->getTable("product_temp_cart"),
        'quote_id',
        [
          "type" => Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
          "nullable" => true
        ]
      );
       $setup->getConnection()->addColumn(
        $setup->getTable("product_temp_cart"),
        'quote_id',
        [
          "type" => Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
          "nullable" => true
        ]
      );

    }
    $setup->endSetup();
    }
 }
```

Is it possible to create a table within an existing module?

> If yes can anyone please share the solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, I was just checking it. We can do this by upgrade schema by using upgrae in the following way.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/157350/create-new-table-with-upgrade-scripts-in-custom-module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a table by InstallSchema.php

If you forgot to create a table first time, You have to delete module entry from **setup_module** table. You can find your module name like **Namespace_Modulename** in this table. just delete your module entry and run below command

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

It will create your table.

Comment: Is any other possibilities, without deleting module from setup?

Comment: Yes. You can create by UpgradeSchema.php.

Comment: If you are creating by UpgradeSchema.php, you have to add same version to module.xml.

Comment: Can you pls update me code

Comment: Which code you need to update?

Comment: How to create table using upgrade schema

Comment: Did you have tried with above UpgradeSchema.php file code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88773/discussion-between-jafar-pinjar-and-suresh-chikani).

Comment: yes, i tried it, it is showing base table not found error

Answer (score 2):

`UpgradeScheme` only works when you need to update your **existing table**.
If your existing module does not contain the table yet, what you need to do is find the `setup_module` table in your Database.

- Find the Entry of your module by name.
- Delete the entry of your module.
- Create `Setup/InstallSchema.php`, create the complete script.
- Then run setup:

> `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

This will then create the non-existent table (from `InstallSchema`) and run `UpgradeSchema` right afterwards for version-specific upgrades.

Comment: yes right now I did like that only, but was looking if any other possibilities, OK that's fine, can you look into this one pls, https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/259436/load-custom-template-file-with-argument-as-product-id-or-sku-in-magento2/