# Load Custom Template file with argument as product id or sku in magento2

Tags: magento2, layout, product-attribute, product-urls

I have created a custom module and calling that template file from the CMS page as like below.

```
 {{block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Custom"    template="Vendor_Module::custom.phtml"}}
```

In templates/custom.phtml

I am fetching the all the products with attribute filters.

I am getting product collection and displaying in my template.

```
<?php
  $collection = $block->getCustomCollection();

  foreach($collection $product) {
   $productName = $product->getName();
   $productPrice = $product->getPrice();
   $productUrl = $product->getProductUrl();
   $productId = $product->getProductId();
  ?>
   <div class="" >
     <h2><?php echo $productName; ?></h2>
     <p><?php echo $productPrice; ?></p>
     <p><a href="<?php echo // How to redirect this product to custom template with product Data ?>"><?php echo $productName; ?></a></p>
   </div>

 <?php } ?>
```

Here my question is I need to redirect the Url to my custom template by passing product ID or SKU as arguement to implement add to cart functionality. not to the default product page.

How i can load custom product detail page in this way. Can i get the product data in my custom template here.

Once I get the product data in my custom template, I will fetch the corresponding product information and show it in the page.

Right now it will go to default product detail page. if i provide href as **$productUrl**

Can anyone help me please. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is **not good** to do a `redirect` in **phtml**, if you need this in the phtml, this mean that your architecture is not good, the redirection must be done in the controller, I guess your need to send that params in another page ? so you have to do a `controller`, you get that params inside then you do kindly your redirect.

To redirect in controller:

```
$this->_redirect('router/controllerfolder/controllername');
```

With params:

```
$resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
$params = array('param1' => 'value', 'param2' => 'value2');
$resultRedirect->setPath('router/controllerfolder/controllername', ['params' => $params]);
return $resultRedirect;
```

Comment: @Prince, how to get that URL inside my href? I am not cleared with your answer actually..

Comment: Once it redirect to custom template, can I get the specific product I'd in it?, can you pls help with code how to get href value for each item of collection like in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Redirecting in phtml is not good approach but for instance lets say you have product id and product sku.
Now First getBaseUrl.

> ```
> <?php
>   $collection = $block->getCustomCollection();
>   foreach($collection $product) {
>    $productName = $product->getName();
>   $productPrice = $product->getPrice();
> $productUrl = $product->getProductUrl();
> $productId = $product->getProductId();
> ?>
> <div class="" >
>  <h2><?php echo $productName; ?></h2>
>  <p><?php echo $productPrice; ?></p>
>  <p><a href="<?php $block->getBaseUrl().'routename/controller/action/'.$productId ?>"><?php echo $productName; ?></a></p>
> ```

this is how you can redirect you page with productId.

Comment: this will redirect to controller with I'd, the resulting page should be loaded with template with some HTML like get product image and display in there, how can I load custom template from the new controller with the id or sku

Comment: You got what I am trying here exactly? Once href is clicked, I need to load my custom template with product info of that I'd.